# Update a string to follow a specific format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in my database that stores a string of numbers, separated by commas.

```
,,133,,,,444,,,,555,,,,6,
```

Rules:

- The first number in the string is always preceded by 2 commas
- There are always 4 commas between the middle numbers
- The last number only has 1 comma after it

The example above is how I always want the string to look..

What happens is when some of these numbers are removed the updated string looks like this:

```
,,31,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,998,,,,476,,,,,
```

Making it look messy in the database and sometimes causing trouble with the extra commas when I try to output each number

I've been manually updating each value to follow the format I want but I'd like to make a script that runs each night and takes each of these strings and updates them with the correct format following the rules I listed above.

What can I use to format the string to follow the rules above?

Comment: You should serious consider reformat your database. Save data (Numbers) as a comma separated string is a very bad idea.

Comment: Why not create four columns on the database and later create a string with the format that you need by using the value of each column?

Comment: Theoretically, there could be an infinite amount of numbers in the string

Comment: then, create a table to store the numbers

Comment: I'm pretty sure that problem that you have is about database design.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thanks for the suggestion. I will make a new table to store these numbers and reference the customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a php script that loads the values from the database, manipulate the rows, and store the manipulated values back to the database. I don't know what database and table structure you use, but the manipulation part is simple:

```
// load the string from the database into the $value variable
$numbers= preg_split("/,+/", $value); // split the string 
$numbers= array_filter( $numbers);  // remove empty array elements
$newvalue = implode(',,,,', $numbers); // join the array elements to a string separated by ,,,,
$newvalue = ',,' . $newvalue . ',';  // add ,, at the beginning and , at the end of the new value
// store $newvalue in the database
```